# Log4j - how can i hide the startup configuration messages from log4j

Tags: logging, log4j, startup

I am working on a command line application that using log4j (1.7.10).

In the log4j.xml, the application has 4 appenders configured, for different types of logs, as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"
debug="true">

<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="regularAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <param name="file" value="./target/logs/develop.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601}|%p|%t|%m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="errorsAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <param name="file" value="./target/logs/errors.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601}|%p|%t|%m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

 <!-- with keystore in config -->
 <appender name="secure-appender" class="com.company.slogger.SecureAppender">
    <param name="file" value="./target/logs/secure.log" />
    <param name="pattern" value="%d{ISO8601}|%p|%t|%m%n" />
    <param name="verifyPattern" value="TIMESTAMP|LEVEL|THREAD|MESSAGE" />
    <param name="numberLogLines" value="10000" />
    <param name="timerLogMilliseconds" value="300000" />
    <param name="triggeringTime" value="3600000" />
    <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <param name="logFileNamePolicyName" value="SEQUENTIAL_DATE_FILENAME" />
</appender>-->

<logger name="std">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="regularAppender" />
</logger>

<!--Secure logger -->
<logger name="SecureLogger" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="secure-appender" />
</logger>

<root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

The logging works fine. The problem is that when the application is startuping, about 30 lines of log4j configuration messages are displayed on the screen, as shown below:

```
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 61 and column 23
log4j:WARN The content of element type "log4j:configuration" must match "(renderer*,appender*,(category|logger)*,root?,categoryFactory?)".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [std] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for std is  [INFO].
log4j: std level set to INFO
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender]
log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [10].
log4j: Setting property [file] to [./target/logs/develop.log].
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ISO8601}|%p|%t|%m%n].
log4j: setFile called: ./target/logs/develop.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Adding appender named [regularAppender] to category [std].
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [errorLog] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for errorLog is  [INFO].
log4j: errorLog level set to INFO
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender]
log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [10].
log4j: Setting property [file] to [./target/logs/errors.log].
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ISO8601}|%p|%t|%m%n].
log4j: setFile called: ./target/logs/errors.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Adding appender named [errorsAppender] to category [errorLog].
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
....
```

This is a command line application, so it does not look very nice to the user to see all these messages at startup.

How can I configure log4j to write these messages to a log file, instead of to the screen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had the similar issue. I Solved it with changing the attribute of `log4j:configuration` tag from `debug="true"` to `debug="false"`.